# How to set arguments of 'build_fn' of Keras's scikit learn API separately?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, keras, callable

```
def create_model(input_shape, lr):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(20, input_shape, 'relu'))
    opt = optimizers.Adam(lr)
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=opt)
    return model

clf = KerasClassifier(build_fn= create_model, input_shape=10,batch_size=25)
list_of_learning_rates = [1e-3,1e-2]
list_of_epochs = [50,100]
gridSearch(clf, list_of_learning_rates, list_of_epochs)
```

I wrote my own grid search code due to specific reason and it is written in a way that I have to initialize the classifier I am using and passed the classifier to the grid search function, with a list of parameters.The example is above. How do I specifically set the `epochs` and `lr` arguments within my `gridSearch` function? I am thinking of using `functools.partial` but I am not sure how, something along the line of: `functools.partial(clf, lr=list_of_learning_rates[0], epcohs=list_of_epochs[0])`, but `clf` is not a function so this does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question. I may use the `set_params()` function of `clf`. For example, `d={'epochs':10, 'lr':1e-3}`, I can run this to set the parameters: `clf.set_params(**d)`.